# Running a Java program from Protractor

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

Let's say I have a Java program for setting up and cleaning up data for end to end tests. It can delete everything from all tables, populate them with some initial data, that kind of stuff.

Is there any way to execute it from within Protractor?

I'm interested in both a way to do it right from the spec (e.g. in `beforeEach` and `afterEach`) as well as having Protractor do it between tests.

Answer (score 1):

Since Protractor is a NodeJS application you can use NodeJS API.

I had a similar need and I executed Maven/Java from using Node's [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module's exec method. The problem was performance, since it needed to start a new JVM instance on each call to exec.

Its not ideal but it does the job...

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
try {
    var child = process.exec('mvn verify',
        function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
            console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
            if (error !== null) {
                console.error('exec error: ' + error);
                deferred.reject();
            }
            else {
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        });
} catch (err) {
    console.error('Caught ' + err);
}
return deferred.promise;
```

You can explore the [node-java](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java) project.